# How do I re-render v-on after creating new object in existing object in Vue

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

My vue component re-render after using the push method to add new data to an object.
However I need to add a new object to an existing one.
The push method however does not work in this case, so I am using the following for that.
This works as expected but now the v-on does not re-render.

```
const newObj = { examples: { example: 'blabla', answer: 'more blabla' } }
  this.test[x].group[y] = Object.assign(this.test[x].group[y], newObj)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.test[x].group[y]))
```

The following does re-render but does not add a new object to the existing object.
For this to work the `examples` object already needs to exist within the object

```
this.cards[x].group[y].examples.push({
        examples: {
          example: 'bla',
          answer: 'more blabla'
        }
      })
```

This does not work

```
this.cards[x].group[y].push({
        examples: {
          example: 'bla',
          answer: 'more blabla'
        }
      })
```

Comment: This is because those properties do not exist at the time that the [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) is established. You can use `Vue.set(object, property, value)` to ensure reactivity is maintained.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy, this let me to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html for information about reactivity. I tried the following but that returned in the error: `Vue is not defined`  `Vue.set(this.test[x].group[y] = Object.assign(this.test[x].group[y], newObj))`

Comment: I tried the following as well but that didnt work as well: `this.test[x].group[y] = Object.assign({}, this.test[x].group[y], newObj)`

Comment: @MK01111000 Did you import `Vue`? `import Vue from 'vue'`. Or from a component method you can use `this.$set()` instead. The code in your second comment won't work because Vue cannot detect array element assignment ([docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)).

Comment: importing Vue solved the error. What is remaining is the following: `Vue.set(this.test[x].group[y] = Object.assign(this.test[x].group[y], newObj))` this replaces already existing data. I would like to append new data. Is this possible?